# Installing PostgreSQL on Windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, user-accounts

I'm in a bit of a mess here. I installed PostgreSQL on my Vista computer a couple of days ago but then when asked to enter the password for the postgre user account I couldn't remember it (allegedly I was asked during setup but I don't remember that).

Anyway, so I uninstalled Pg with the intention of reinstalling it, removed the user account, it's /Users/ directory and it's special privelleges ("Advanced user profile properties") but when I come to install Pg it seems to think the account still exists as when I supply a password during setup it says that it is not the correct password - meaning that the account still exists somewhere.

Is there anyway I can recover this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Computer Management. There under "Local Users and Groups" you can see all users created for your system. Remove "postgres" and reinstall PostgreSQL.

Comment: Or you can just reset the account's password while you're there.

Comment: Where abouts is the "Local Users and Groups" category? Here is what I see: http://www.kalleload.net/uploads/jrwddejjnheh.png

Comment: Hmm, that should be under "System Tools" actually. Are you in some kind of AD domain? Try "net user" from the command line. It should show you a list of users. "net user /?" will list available operations and their syntax.

Comment: This PC is a little borked (the Admin Tools folder was actually empty when I looked first - had to restore the shortcuts) but I've been successfully able to remove the user using net user postgres /DELETE. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Open a command prompt with the administrator rights.
i.e. Right click on command prompt icon -> Run as Administrator

Use the following command to change the password:

!important: CASE and SHOULD BE RUNNING AS ADMINISTRATOR

```
NET USER postgres <NEW_PASSWORD>
```

Comment: this worked a treat for me - i suspect my biggest problem was repeatedly putting to s's in postgresssss ;-)

Answer (score 1):

On Vista you can go to Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Manage Another Accounts
then select user postgres, change the password if you forget your last password.